How is the speed of the water in the Seine during the Olympic Games in Paris accounted for?
The triathlon competition(s) during the 2024 Olympic Games in Paris will take place in the Seine for the swimming part.
The Seine is a river so water flows with or against the swimmers, and its speed is variable depending on the place.
How is this accounted for? Are results in this triathlon comparable to others?

In terms of current direction compared to swim direction, that is balanced out by repeating two laps of a bidirectional course:

The athletes will have the current at their backs for the first half of each lap, which takes them under the Pont des Invalides, a bridge that the bike and run courses take athletes over later in the race. After passing under the bridge, athletes will take a left hand turn then another left hand turn to come back upstream toward the pontoon. They’ll exit on the right side of the pontoon, take a left hand turn to run about 20 meters on the pontoon, then dive back in for the second loop.

In terms of comparability to other races, the article above reports mens' times under 60 seconds per 100 metres going downstream, but closer to 80 seconds per 100 metres going upstream.
Meanwhile, results from elite competition such as the World Triathlon Championship finals have the top-ranked men finishing 1500 metre swim in 18 to 19 minutes, and women in 19 to 20 minutes. These average out to around 1:13, suggesting the Paris 2024 times are within expected ranges overall.
The Seine faced significantly higher volumetric flows in the month prior to the Games due to excessive rain, with peak flow above 670 cumec on 23 June and 580 cumec on 12 July, well over the typical summer flow of 100 to 150 cumec. However, flows have abated to under 400 cumec and decreasing since 18 July, making it unlikely that this will make the times incomparable.
